# How do I build maven project into multiple dirs?

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Maven, and my maven project looks like this:

```
Project_Name/
    \_________src
               \___com.xxx.aaa
               \___com.xxx.bbb
    \_________conf
               \___application.xml
               \___config.properties
               \___startup.sh
```

Now I want to compile my project into three directories:

```
   Project_Name.zip
          \___________bin
                       \______startup.sh
          \___________conf
                       \______all configuration files.
          \___________lib
                       \______all dependencies and java code.
```

How do I make it possible ?

Comment: Based on Maven conventions your layout is wrong. The sources are located in `src/main/java`. Configuration files are located in `src/main/resources`. To create a startup.sh script you could use appassembler-maven-plugin. To create a zip file you can use maven-assembly-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use maven-assembly-plugin. Take a look at this article http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/creating-a-runnable-binary-distribution-with-maven-assembly-plugin/